# stack overflow error in native method without apparent reason

Tags: dart, mixpanel, dart2js

I receive a stack overflow error without any repeating pattern when calling a wrapper for a native method

here's my adapter

```
import 'dart:js';

import 'package:share_place/users/user.dart';
import 'package:logging/logging.dart';
class MixPanel {
  Logger log = new Logger("MixPanel");
  JsObject mixpanel;
  init(User user) {
    mixpanel = context["mixpanel"];
    if( user != null ) {
      mixpanel.callMethod("identify", [user.id]);
      mixpanel['people'].callMethod("set", [new JsObject.jsify({
        "\$email": user.mainMail,
        "\$first_name": user.displayName,
        "name": user.displayName,
        "skype": user.skype,
        "photoId": "/auth/gridfs/file/${user.photoIdM}/picture.x"
      })]);
    }
  }

  void track(String action, {Map data:null}) {
    log.fine("calling mixpanel with action '$action', $mixpanel");
    assert(mixpanel != null, "mixpanel must be initialized before calling this method");

    mixpanel.callMethod("track", [action, data != null ? new JsObject.jsify(data) : ""]);
  }


}
```

here's the stack of my call, notice there's no repeating pattern, is it possible that we really reached to max allowed sequential calls?:

```
html_dart2js.dart:3558 SEVERE - Environment : mix panel call failed Stack Overflow
dart.alh.$1 @ html_dart2js.dart:3558
dart.Fj.func @ zone.dart:1132
o3 @ zone.dart:1309
aN @ stream_impl.dart:330
dart.eu.cS @ stream_impl.dart:257
aN @ broadcast_stream_controller.dart:379
zU @ broadcast_stream_controller.dart:254
R3 @ logging.dart:195
lC @ main.dart.js:33122
FM @ logging.dart:226
fk @ main.dart.js:33135
dL @ environment.dart:344
J.cE @ main.dart.js:54489
(anonymous) @ info_popup.dart:57
(anonymous) @ async_patch.dart:213
dart.acx.$2 @ async_patch.dart:237
dart.aby.$1 @ async_patch.dart:187
dart.Fj.func @ zone.dart:1128
Ed @ zone.dart:685
dart.cJ.Wm @ ng_zone.dart:184
(anonymous) @ VM5236:2
jp @ zone.dart:1012
PX @ future_impl.dart:129
$0 @ future_impl.dart:636
iN @ future_impl.dart:665
du @ future_impl.dart:468
(anonymous) @ future_impl.dart:51
J.Nd @ main.dart.js:54209
K @ async_patch.dart:164
(anonymous) @ place_service.dart:602
(anonymous) @ async_patch.dart:213
dart.acx.$2 @ async_patch.dart:237
dart.aby.$1 @ async_patch.dart:187
dart.Fj.func @ zone.dart:1128
Ed @ zone.dart:685
dart.cJ.Wm @ ng_zone.dart:184
(anonymous) @ VM5236:2
jp @ zone.dart:1012
PX @ future_impl.dart:129
$0 @ future_impl.dart:636
iN @ future_impl.dart:665
du @ future_impl.dart:468
(anonymous) @ future_impl.dart:51
J.Nd @ main.dart.js:54209
K @ async_patch.dart:164
(anonymous) @ place_service.dart:108
(anonymous) @ async_patch.dart:213
dart.acx.$2 @ async_patch.dart:237
dart.aby.$1 @ async_patch.dart:187
dart.Fj.func @ zone.dart:1128
Ed @ zone.dart:685
dart.cJ.Wm @ ng_zone.dart:184
(anonymous) @ VM5236:2
jp @ zone.dart:1012
PX @ future_impl.dart:129
$0 @ future_impl.dart:636
iN @ future_impl.dart:665
tc @ future_impl.dart:478
dart.a7C.$0 @ future_impl.dart:510
dart.Wc.$0 @ ng_zone.dart:161
dart.Fh.func @ zone.dart:1120
E8 @ zone.dart:675
dart.cJ.Wi @ ng_zone.dart:175
(anonymous) @ VM5234:2
cz @ zone.dart:1001
hU @ zone.dart:901
dart.a7e.$0 @ zone.dart:926
acj @ schedule_microtask.dart:41
dart.auX @ schedule_microtask.dart:50
dart.a6A.$1 @ async_patch.dart:51
$0 @ js_helper.dart:2456
nl @ isolate_helper.dart:474
lK @ isolate_helper.dart:59
dart.al3 @ js_helper.dart:2456
(anonymous) @ js_helper.dart:2476
childList (async)
$1 @ async_patch.dart:67
Fm @ async_patch.dart:28
dart.u8 @ zone.dart:1176
wW @ zone.dart:743
dart.cJ.VY @ ng_zone.dart:169
(anonymous) @ VM5240:2
hY @ zone.dart:1076
b3 @ future_impl.dart:509
(anonymous) @ future_impl.dart:40
dart.Q2.$1 @ browser_client.dart:62
dart.Fj.func @ zone.dart:1128
Ed @ zone.dart:685
dart.cJ.Wm @ ng_zone.dart:184
(anonymous) @ VM5236:2
jp @ zone.dart:1012
PX @ future_impl.dart:129
$0 @ future_impl.dart:636
iN @ future_impl.dart:665
du @ future_impl.dart:468
k0 @ stream_pipe.dart:63
dart.a_s.$1 @ stream.dart:997
dart.a7v.$1 @ html_dart2js.dart:42920
dart.Fj.func @ zone.dart:1132
Ed @ zone.dart:685
dart.cJ.Wm @ ng_zone.dart:184
(anonymous) @ VM5236:2
jp @ zone.dart:1012
o3 @ zone.dart:909
dart.a7g.$1 @ zone.dart:936
$0 @ js_helper.dart:2456
nl @ isolate_helper.dart:474
lK @ isolate_helper.dart:59
dart.al3 @ js_helper.dart:2456
(anonymous) @ js_helper.dart:2476
FileReader (async)
dart.Q4.$1 @ browser_client.dart:77
dart.Fj.func @ zone.dart:1128
Ed @ zone.dart:685
dart.cJ.Wm @ ng_zone.dart:184
(anonymous) @ VM5236:2
jp @ zone.dart:1012
PX @ future_impl.dart:129
$0 @ future_impl.dart:636
iN @ future_impl.dart:665
du @ future_impl.dart:468
k0 @ stream_pipe.dart:63
dart.a_s.$1 @ stream.dart:997
dart.a7v.$1 @ html_dart2js.dart:42920
dart.Fj.func @ zone.dart:1132
Ed @ zone.dart:685
dart.cJ.Wm @ ng_zone.dart:184
(anonymous) @ VM5236:2
jp @ zone.dart:1012
o3 @ zone.dart:909
dart.a7g.$1 @ zone.dart:936
$0 @ js_helper.dart:2456
nl @ isolate_helper.dart:474
lK @ isolate_helper.dart:59
dart.al3 @ js_helper.dart:2456
(anonymous) @ js_helper.dart:2476
XMLHttpRequest.send (async)
(anonymous) @ html_dart2js.dart:20547
J.ha @ main.dart.js:54426
(anonymous) @ browser_client.dart:88
(anonymous) @ async_patch.dart:213
dart.acx.$2 @ async_patch.dart:237
dart.aby.$1 @ async_patch.dart:187
dart.Fj.func @ zone.dart:1128
Ed @ zone.dart:685
dart.cJ.Wm @ ng_zone.dart:184
(anonymous) @ VM5236:2
jp @ zone.dart:1012
PX @ future_impl.dart:129
$0 @ future_impl.dart:636
iN @ future_impl.dart:665
tc @ future_impl.dart:478
dart.a7C.$0 @ future_impl.dart:510
dart.Wc.$0 @ ng_zone.dart:161
dart.Fh.func @ zone.dart:1120
E8 @ zone.dart:675
dart.cJ.Wi @ ng_zone.dart:175
(anonymous) @ VM5234:2
cz @ zone.dart:1001
hU @ zone.dart:901
dart.a7e.$0 @ zone.dart:926
acj @ schedule_microtask.dart:41
dart.auX @ schedule_microtask.dart:50
dart.a6A.$1 @ async_patch.dart:51
$0 @ js_helper.dart:2456
nl @ isolate_helper.dart:474
lK @ isolate_helper.dart:59
dart.al3 @ js_helper.dart:2456
(anonymous) @ js_helper.dart:2476
childList (async)
$1 @ async_patch.dart:67
Fm @ async_patch.dart:28
dart.u8 @ zone.dart:1176
wW @ zone.dart:743
dart.cJ.VY @ ng_zone.dart:169
(anonymous) @ VM5240:2
hY @ zone.dart:1076
kH @ future_impl.dart:342
um @ future_impl.dart:251
tQ @ async_patch.dart:206
L @ async_patch.dart:142
U @ info_popup.dart:59
n @ files_comp.template.dart:1397
w @ app_view.dart:341
I @ view_container.dart:57
n @ files_comp.template.dart:1222
w @ app_view.dart:341
I @ view_container.dart:57
n @ files_comp.template.dart:677
w @ app_view.dart:341
I @ view_container.dart:57
n @ files_comp.template.dart:532
w @ app_view.dart:341
I @ view_container.dart:57
n @ files_comp.template.dart:488
w @ app_view.dart:341
I @ view_container.dart:57
n @ files_comp.template.dart:337
w @ app_view.dart:341
I @ view_container.dart:57
n @ files_comp.template.dart:173
w @ app_view.dart:341
n @ app_component.template.dart:761
w @ app_view.dart:341
n @ app_component.template.dart:1980
w @ app_view.dart:341
MO @ view_ref.dart:104
wu @ application_ref.dart:422
dart.Pl.$0 @ application_ref.dart:278
dart.Fh.func @ zone.dart:1120
E8 @ zone.dart:675
dart.cJ.Wi @ ng_zone.dart:175
(anonymous) @ VM5234:2
cz @ zone.dart:1001
hU @ zone.dart:901
hU @ ng_zone.dart:310
dart.Ps.$1 @ application_ref.dart:277
o3 @ zone.dart:1307
aN @ stream_impl.dart:330
dart.eu.cS @ stream_impl.dart:257
$1 @ broadcast_stream_controller.dart:387
tq @ broadcast_stream_controller.dart:328
aN @ broadcast_stream_controller.dart:386
mv @ broadcast_stream_controller.dart:254
dart.cJ.Wi @ ng_zone.dart:213
(anonymous) @ VM5234:2
cz @ zone.dart:1001
hU @ zone.dart:901
hU @ ng_zone.dart:310
dart.Ph.$1 @ app_view.dart:566
$0 @ js_helper.dart:2456
nl @ isolate_helper.dart:474
lK @ isolate_helper.dart:59
dart.al3 @ js_helper.dart:2456
(anonymous) @ js_helper.dart:2476
js_primitives.dart:30 popup init
```

I cannot find where to start to solve this issue.

Just for SF I must add this text so there's not too much code for too few text.
Just for SF I must add this text so there's not too much code for too few text.
Just for SF I must add this text so there's not too much code for too few text.
Just for SF I must add this text so there's not too much code for too few text.
Just for SF I must add this text so there's not too much code for too few text.
Just for SF I must add this text so there's not too much code for too few text.
Just for SF I must add this text so there's not too much code for too few text.
Just for SF I must add this text so there's not too much code for too few text.
Just for SF I must add this text so there's not too much code for too few text.

Comment: Perhaps you get a better stack trace with `pub build --mode=debug`? Is this only in Chrome or also in Dartium with `pub serve`?

Comment: isn't `mixpanel.callMethod("track",` resulting in a call to `void track(String action, {Map data:null}) {`?

Answer (score 1):

The error was due to an argument I was passing to the method that was badly serialized.

Sorry I can't give any more details, removing an argument from the call made it ok (I took out the data I wanted from the argument to pass as independent parameters)